# Pandas: How do you map XLSX column names with spaces, to dataclass variable name without changing XLSX column values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Consider the following XLSX table:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| Billy | Madison |
| Happy | Gilmore |

Now consider the following Dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
first_name: str
last_name: str


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_excel('people.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', skiprows=3, na_values='')
    people = df.values.tolist()
    people_instances = [Person]
    for person in people:
        people_instances.append(Person(*person))
```

I want to know if there is a way to map the XLSX column value to the dataclass variable name so I don't have to change the XLSX column value without a space.